# Jenkins: Slave selection based on user's choice

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure a jenkins job so that **based** on the **choice** of the user the node/slave should be selected.

```
example : if choice = windows ->slave1
          if choice = Linux ->slave2
```

I've tried with configuration matrix i'm getting error that the nodes are offline.Is there any plugin to do such selections in jenkins

Comment: Why do you need this feature? Normally a particular build requires a certain software environment to be installed which is why the build job needs to explicitly target a specific slave tag. Allowing the user to choose seems odd to me.... What's the use case?

Comment: Hi Mark my use case is to generate OS specific builds for a GIT tag so for each OSTYPE a build gets generated in its dedicated machine....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to create two build jobs that are then tagged to a specific slave.
When you configure the job you can add labels to it that specify the requirements for this job.
Example:

- linux-build, add the label linux
- windows-build: add the label windows

Then, when you create the slaves you need to assign them labels as well specifying the capabilities.

Example:

- Windows system, add the windows label
- Linux system, add the linux label

After this your builds will automatically go to the correct system and you never have to specify anything again. This is better then having to manually specify and trigger a job.

One more advantage, if the job fails you know why.. maybe you linux job always succeeds but you windows job always fails, if you combine this in one job you can't really see this pattern but if you have two separate builds you will immediately see a dark cloud forming over you windows build.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the following plugin:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

I used the Jenkins CLI to implement the dynamical slave selection.
1) create two jobs: job A triggers job B
2) at job A, input the followings at Build/Execute Shell

```
 if choice = windows, SERVER=slave1
 if choice = Linux, SERVER=slave2
 java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http_to_jenkins-server:port build buildname -p SERVER_LABEL=$SERVER -v -w --username yourusername --password yourpassword
```

3) at job B, select "This build is parameterized" and add a String Parameter SERVER.

Hope it helps.